# Displaying a list of YouTube sites (WebView) via ViewPager

Tags: android, webview, youtube, android-viewpager

I would like to display a list of music tunes in ViewPager.
So I use WebView as a view item in the pager. The code below works perfectly for every site except YouTube.

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
  WebView w=new WebView(cxt);
  w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  w.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
  w.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com");
  ((ViewPager) collection).addView(w,0);
  return w;
}
```

The problem is that I couldn't swipe the pager; instead, Android asks me whether to "complete action" using "Internet" or "TubeMate". Once selected, the video is no longer displayed inside my app. Is there any way to force Android to display YouTube contents right inside my app rather than Internet Browser?

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution myself. Add these lines before loadUrl would solve the problem:

```
w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

This would override the default action (Internet Browser) with using my own WebView.

Comment: The YouTube site is shown as expected, but unfortunately I couldn't play (or even click the play button) YouTube videos inside my WebView. Help!